# Allow user to read only own content with firebase rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to set users to get only own objects. I have a tasks which have 3 attributes on fb-database: task-text, datetime, user. user have user uid. I want to write a rule that allow user to read only own tasks.

So far I have this and it dont work:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "tasks": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == data.child('user').val()",
            ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you restructured it so that it is: root > userId > task(s), then you could do: rules > $uid > ".read" : "auth != null && $uid==auth.uid".

Comment: Thanks Linxy! That worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to break up the tasks by user, so you'll have a structure that looks like:

```
root
  tasks
    Puf
      ...
    Andrew
      ...
    James
      ...
```

This can be secured via rules that look like:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "tasks": {
            "$userId": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $userId",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $userId",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually Linxy comment worked for me.